# how to use htaccess to allow certain domains to load php file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a php file ac.php on ac folder

how can I use htaccess to allow ac.php be accessed by certain domains only. eg. domain1.me, domain2.com

currently i have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain1\.me [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

but my ac.php file is still not accessible with both domains.

Comment: Not reliably, but if it would work _if_ the referer was set, but take into account it's a full url, so it usually starts with `http(s)://`. However this is easily circumvented, and some people will be forbidden which are genuinely coming from that domain. Letting the originating domain generating access tokens would be a more robust solution, or proxy the service ac.php provides on their own domain.

Comment: Maybe this Q/A helps you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859752/configure-only-allow-specific-domains-to-access-certain-folders-using-htaccess