# Limit API access to own domain?

Tags: ajax, api, restrictions

I offer an API (geocoding) and want to provide users with a demo website. This site would query the API through AJAX. Is there some way to limit the access so only requests from the website would be accepted in order to prevent free unlimited access to the API?

Comment: You could easily use `.htaccess` to achieve this. This link might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859752/configure-only-allow-specific-domains-to-access-certain-folders-using-htaccess

Comment: What technology is used to serve the api?

Comment: I use node.js (aws api gateway/lambda)

Answer (score -1):

you can use nginx to check request referer header:

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*) {
    if ($http_referer !~ "^http://yourdomain.com"){
        return 403;
    }
}
```