# Disable public access for all requests

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following scenario:

- I have text, images, videos in my root folder.
- The data is sensitive

I would like to:

- Limit any public direct access, but I would like to be able to access/copy them from a particular domain like `abc.com`.

Is this possible using .htaccess, if `yes` than how?

Comment: You can have a condition in htaccess that relates to the domain so I believe it's possible. Follow those guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131023/998096

Comment: There is no meaningful notion of access "from a particular domain".

Answer (score 1):

on the folder you wish to protect create an .htaccess file and put on it

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from Your_IP_ADDRESS
```